# Are there any free Windows Perl IDE with debugging?

Tags: perl, debugging, ide

Are there any free Perl IDEs out there for Windows that have debugging capabilities, syntax highlighting, and possibly even IntelliSense?

Comment: Link leads to http://www.perlmonks.org/?node=Perl%20Development%20Tools

Comment: Since this question is closed, I hope it will be migrated to http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is an overview of Perl IDE's [here](http://www.perlide.org/). I find Padre very promising, but I'm not sure it already has all features you need (if not it probably will soon).

Comment: This link is awesome. Best comment.

Comment: I find Padre to be pretty disappointing. It works; but debugging is almost unusable. It will also occasionally crash and seemingly not be able to re-launch for a good while.

Answer (score 7):

Eclipse with addons perhaps?

Have a look at EPIC

http://www.epic-ide.org/

Comment: Unfortunately, debugging in EPIC (stable) is unusable for me. It used to work but lately the debugger can only be started once. After that, Eclipse needs to be restarted to use it again...

Answer (score 5):

This isn't free but you could have a look at Komodo ([ActiveState](http://www.activestate.com/komodo/)). When I looked at it a few years ago they were offering a free license for open source developers.

Comment: I'd love to use Komodo but it's way too expensive.

Comment: I use Komodo Edit, which is the free version, unfortunately it doesn't do everything of the full version, Komodo IDE.

Answer (score 4):

Padre: http://padre.perlide.org/

GNU/Emacs with cperl-mode: http://gnu.org/software/emacs

Emacs has better editing capabilities (and hilights Perl better, ironically), but Padre might be enough for you.

Comment: Emacs also have an integrated debugger (gud) with Perl support. With Devel::PerlySense the debugger becomes slightly easier to use.

Answer (score 2):

[perlfaq3](http://faq.perl.org/perlfaq3.html) lists several [IDEs for Windows](http://faq.perl.org/perlfaq3.html#Is_there_an_IDE_or_W).

Answer (score 1):

I use [enginsite Perl Editor lite version](http://www.enginsite.com/Download.htm), mainly for the function, variable breakdown feature and the compile/run feature.

if you want more feature then you might want to look at the full version.

Answer (score 1):

Komodo Edit from ActiveState supports debugging and it's cross-platform.

Comment: Komodo IDE it self is great but it costs $300 or so. Komodo Edit has no debugger feature so it's disqualified.

Comment: Mmm actually Komodo Edit shows the errors in the code while you type.

Comment: @tunnuz I think that is called syntax-checking, not debugging, which should also tell us what the variables are, so as to keep track on the errors: legitimate syntaxes can lead to huge errors as well.